# How to send data when mouse click that is runing function actionPerformed(ActionEvent l)

Tags: java

here is my code .
they are from two files.

TClient.java

```
public class TClient{
public static void main(String[] agrs){                 
        String ip=null;//string ip
        LayoutO frame; 
        frame = new LayoutO();
        frame.setVisible(true);         
}
```

LayoutO.java

```
 public class LayoutO extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
public LayoutO() {

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(59, 157, 240, 39);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("SUBMIT");
    btnSubmit.setBounds(93, 236, 172, 77);
    contentPane.add(btnSubmit);

    btnSubmit.addActionListener(this);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
    String str=textField.getText();//the aim string is here
    }
}
```

i want to use this GUI to get textField's text when press "submit" button.

but the function of actionPerformed do not have return thing.

How could i get the aim string(aim string at the last line of the LayoutO.java) to evaluate
the string 'ip'(the string in main).

Comment: what's wrong with this code?

Comment: what do you mean by this? "get aim String to evaluate the string 'ip'"

Comment: @Tala when mouse click ,can get the string from the textField .I just don't kown how to fetch it in the main function

Comment: you can have a string field in LayoutO and populate in actionPerformedMethod. Also you'll have to wait in main method and notify when the value is set

Comment: @Tala but how can my string ip get the textField thing.

Comment: it depends on what you want. do you want to see GUI and press the button once and start a huge task or you want to frequently change the text field and do some job with it?

Comment: @Tala i  want press the button once and get the value ,and use it in the main of ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a listener, like in `Layout0` constructor:

```
 btnSubmit.addActionListener(this);
```

this won't wait for an action. I will simply "register" the listener and return. When an event occur, `actioPerformed` will be called.

You should create a method in TClient to do things when a new string was entered.

The listener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
    String str=textField.getText();//the aim string is here
    TClient.newStringSubmited(str);
}
```

And in TClient:

```
public void newStringSubmited(String str) {

     //do what you want with the string
}
```

Comment: note that this is a little different then author wants. Main thread will end and newStringSubmited will be executed in the same thread as actionPerformed.

Comment: You're right. If he wants the string in this won't work. And a thread should be created to get out of EDT.

Comment: @jeanwaghetti thanks . it's actually what i want .though main was end , the program wasn't end. can continue work througn the actionPerformed method

Comment: But as stated in before, you should create a new thread for managing GUI events. Otherwise, the code will be executed in Event Dispatch Thread and your GUI may become unresponsive. Other comment: `main()` set visible the frame. Your application will be "alive" until you dispose the frames and dialogs you created.

Answer (score 1):

The question is: Where should the input "aim" String go? Into the TClient class or an instance of it? The String "ip" in the TClient is inside the main method, hence it is a local variable which does only exist during this method's execution time.

Think about where the input String should go. Then make an attribute or a method into that place so that it can be put there. The ActionListener then needs a reference to that place and can set the input String to that target variable or pass it to a method for processing.